# Significance of 'pagerror.gif'?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-status-code-404

I'm getting strange hits to a non-existant file on my site called 'pagerror.gif'. From some basic Googling it appears to be a file that Internet Explorer looks for in certain situations.

Can anyone verify that, and perhaps provide some additional information about when IE would look for that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, pagerror.gif is the image IE shows on error pages.
Should be located in res://shdoclc.dll/pagerror.gif. (You can enter that in IE to see the icon)

Comment: That's correct, but under what circumstances would IE request that icon from the webserver as opposed to retrieving it from the local computer?

Comment: Probably isn't, could be someone looking for a vuln?
Similar to http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/310684?

Comment: It happened to my co-worker while he was testing stuff on the site, but we didn't notice it in the logs until a week later so the exact conditions were lost. So it appears to be something that IE is doing on its own.